# Autolayout UILabel height changes on second view appearence

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitableview, autolayout

I have a dynamic UILabel in a TableHeaderView ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793078/hide-view-and-reposition-other-view-with-autolayouts)) and everything is okay and fine, but if I set the text of the label to `nil` or `@""` the label keeps the size of the height that it had when the text was in.

I'm changing the text in a different viewController that I'm `presenting modally`. So i would like to show it you in 3 steps:

**Original state**

[image: State one]

**After setting the text to `@""`**

In this step I presented the viewController to remove the text and then I dismiss the viewController to go back to this View.

[image: State two]

**Reappear this View**

So I have to open the editing viewController to just dismiss it again. Then it is like i want it to..:

[image: State three]

Any ideas why? I'm re-sizing the TableViewHeader like this in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
- (void)resizeTableViewHeader
{
    //GET THE SIZE OF THE CONTAINER
    CGSize fittingSize = [self.header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, fittingSize.height);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.header;
}
```

Any idea why I have to visit the View twice?

Comment: While creating the UIlabel set the height to minimum height and when the uilabel will have text it will autoresize its height .Try that .

Comment: I'm doing that and it works, but it isnt when the view reappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it needs constraints updating somewhere, or `layoutIfNeeded`. Other solution could be found in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22270240/1032151).

Comment: I dont got my macbook here atm. Do I can call `layoutIfNeeded` on a UILabel?

Comment: I guess it needs to be placed somewhere above in the view hierarchy, but you could give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

You should implemente the tableViewDelegate method and calculate the header height.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat height = //Calculate the dynamic height.
    return height;
}
```

Comment: That's not about table section header, it's about the whole table view header. (check tableHeaderView)